# Filter on dataset or on tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two tablix on report, and one dataset for providing data to tablix. I have parameter on report that is multiselect and I need, based on values in that parameter, filter result.

Is there any distinction, and if is, what is better solution:

Create filter direct on dataset, or on tablix? Both of them will give me same result, but what is correct or better?

Answer (score 4):

If in doubt, always get as close to your data source as possible.  The ideal is to filter things in a SQL Server view or stored procedure, since this can be optimised; the next best thing is to filter in an SSRS dataset.

Filtering in a tablix item should be a last resort, and will involve reports running considerably more slowly.

There: that's my penn'orth!

Answer (score 3):

There's no definite answer to this question that can apply to all situations.

In your case, since both Tablix objects need the same filter, I'd apply it at the Dataset level; that way you're not duplicating code/logic in the report.

Or even consider applying the filter when generating the Dataset, e.g. if it's from a Stored Procedure, implement a suitable `WHERE` clause to filter at the database level. That way there is less data being transferred unnecessarily.

I would go with whatever is the best for ease of coding and maintainability. Out of the options you've presented Dataset filtering seems to be the way to go.